# Continuing the loop from exception block

Tags: oracle11g

I understand that this question had already been answered and i have referred to that question . However when i am trying to compile the following code whereby i am trying to go through a LOOP which contains an INSERT statement ,if the insert statement  is not successful i need to check if the error thrown by the DML-insert failure is UNIQUE constraint or not ,if it is unique constraint error (-1) then i need to perform an update statement and continue the loop.

Oracle Version : 11g

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TESTSAMPLE" AS



type array_test IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

test_arr array_test := array_test(1,   2,   3);

v_key NUMBER;
dup_chk NUMBER;
v_excp_error_code varchar2(25);


BEGIN

  FOR i IN test_arr.FIRST .. test_arr.LAST

  LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i || ' = ' || test_arr(i));
    dup_chk := test_arr(i);
    INSERT
    INTO trig_test
    VALUES('TEST324',   test_arr(i),   'Y',   'Y') returning KEY
    INTO v_key;

    IF v_key IS NOT NULL THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' commiting insert ' || v_key || ' ' || dup_chk);
      COMMIT;
    END IF;

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_excp_error_code := SQLCODE;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR CODE = ' || v_excp_error_code);

    IF v_excp_error_code = '-1' THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('entered unique constraint exception ' || v_key);

      IF v_key = dup_chk OR v_key IS NULL THEN

        UPDATE trig_test
        SET status = 'tstsample'
        WHERE KEY = v_key;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated ');
        COMMIT;

      END IF;

    ELSE
      RAISE;
    END IF;
  END;  

  END LOOP;

END testsample;
```

The above stored procedure is throwing following compilation error ,

> Error(33,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null    pragma raise return select update while with       <<    continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
>
> Error(56,7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:     ;
>
> Error(59): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map

Highly appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: In case you're not aware, there's a named exception DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX you can catch directly instead of catching OTHERS and then inspecting the SQLCODE: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/named_system.php

Answer (score 2):

you're missing a `begin` after your loop. ie:

```
loop

  begin -- ADD THIS
    dbms_output.put_line(i || ' = ' || test_arr(i));
    dup_chk := test_arr(i);
    insert into trig_test
    values
      ('TEST324', test_arr(i), 'Y', 'Y')
    returning key into v_key;

    if v_key is not null
    then
      dbms_output.put_line(' commiting insert ' || v_key || ' ' || dup_chk);
      commit;
    end if;

  exception
```

instead of trapping `others` though, as your only interested in `ORA-00001` you can just trap `when dup_val_on_index` instead and not check the sqlcode.

Comment: Hi Dazzal, 
 blooper from my side...sorry and thanks very much for the suggestion.